# TinyMCE - prevent auto focus on mceAddControl command

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

When I run this line of command (on a dynamically added element):

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
```

It's auto focus on the element.

Is there a way to prevent the focus?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using v4. `mceAddControl` has been changed from v3 to a new command in the new version. The new command is `mceAddEditor`.

HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea id='instance1'></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
var textArea_id = "instance1";

//V3 command
//tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, textArea_id);

//V4 command
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, textArea_id);

//if you want to focus the editor
//tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', false, textArea_id);
```

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/7sy4m4fy/)